# How to use <spring:message tag in javascript/jQuery/jsp?

Tags: jquery, spring, message

is resulting nothing. Here is my code....

1. src/validationMessages.properties
      fname.error=First name is mandatory.
2. Spring-servlet.xml
    messagesource is configured with basename = validationMessages
3. Jsp code as mentioned above and jQuery as follows....
    Rules:{
          firstname: "required"
      },
     Messages:{
          firstname:{
                required:   ""
          }

   jsp taglib tag is included......

But the tag renders  nothing...........required: " "

Any advice.?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about springs but you can try this.  I've used the same to catch the values in **Struts2** mvc

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
       var message='<spring:message code="${error.code}" text="${error.defaultMessage}"/>'
       alert(message);
    });
```